# Indent at paragraph following an equation and a figure

Tags: spacing, floats

In one section of my document I have several equations. Due to the normal separation of paragraphs trough the equations I do not have any further passages in the text. Somewhere in the middle of the section I want to include a figure. As the section is quite long I don't want to set the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` at the end of the section as the graphic would not be in the right position.

But if I am entering the graphic as shown in the example I get an indent at the beginning of the next paragraph after the equation.

Is there any way to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{equation}
1+2=3
\end{equation}
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
%
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Solution:

Commenting the line `\end{figure}%` prevents the extra space at the beginning of the new paragraph.

Comment: What you get before “Nam dui ligula…” is an interword space, and it is not clear to me whether you want (a) replace that space with a true indent or (b) get rid of the space altogether.  Also, are you aware of the fact that the commands you are using to generate dummy text do alter the terms of the problem?  Try replacing `\lipsum` with `\lipsum*` and commenting out the end-of-line after `\end{figure}` (_i.e.,_ write `\end{figure}%`).

Comment: I want to get rid of the space before the word "Nam dui..." and your suggestion to commenting `\end{figure}%` just did it! Thanks a lot.